# Mongo db query | Join | Create query on two collection

Tags: sql, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Select leadId count on two collection in Mongo DB

Collection 1 : leads

```
{
 leadId:"abc123",
 status:"OPENED",
 stage:"start",
 crossSell:
    {
      cc:
         {
            consent:true,
            shown:[{first:true}]
         }
    }
 }
```

Collection 2 : pdata

```
{
 activeLeadId:"abc123",
 status:"OPENED",
 details:
    [
        {
            rating:10
        },
        {
            rating:9
        }
    ]
}
```

Question : Find leadId count from leads collection join with pdata collection based on below conditions

1. leads.leadId = pdata.activeleadId and
2. leads.status = "OPENED" and
3. leads.crossSell.cc.consent = true and
4. leads.crossSell.cc.shown[0].first = true and
5. pdata.details.rating >= 5

Comment: what is the expected output in json? you want to unwind the arrays first and then do the lookup? or you want lookup with the arrays as they are? for example rating>=5 what it means? array to have at least one >=5, all >=5 or unwind and keep those that >=5?

Comment: Which `status` should be `"OPENED"`? Which or how many `rating`s in the `details` array need to have a value of `5` or higher?

Comment: @Takis expected output is count, I mean howmany records are available with matchin conditions. the array to include in condition which have at least one rating >=5

Comment: @user20042973 I have updated question, at-least one rating in details should have value >= 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a aggregation query,

- `$match` your conditions for leads collection
- `$lookup` with `pdata` collection, pass `leadId` to match with `pdata`
- match required conditions for pdata
- `$limit` to return single document, because we don't need that data in response
- `$match` condition to check is `pdata` is not empty
- `$count` to get total number of records

```
db.leads.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: "OPENED",
      "crossSell.cc.consent": true,
      "crossSell.cc.shown.first": true
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "pdata",
      "let": { "leadId": "$leadId" },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$leadId", "$activeLeadId"] },
            "details.rating": { $gte: 5 }
          }
        },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      "as": "pdata"
    }
  },
  { $match: { pdata: { $ne: [] } } },
  { $count: "count" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/azhGlBH2pJ7)

Comment: 'shown' in leads collection and 'details' field in pdata are array. can we use 'details.rating' on array.

Comment: This is not giving output. Query is always giving output 1 even for "details.rating": { $gte: 20}

Comment: can you provide example documents, that give an output of more than 1 count? you can add documents in the above playground and share the link.

Comment: I have added more documents. https://mongoplayground.net/p/GD6jXrV1MVK

Comment: What is the expected count for these documents?

Comment: expected count is 2